# Adding function in xhrFields in Jquery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to add if condition in xhrFields: in jquery - ajax call?

Ex:

```
xhrFields : { 
   if(flag =='Y'){
   withCredentials: true 
   }
 }
```

Comment: If you'd have bothered to try this, you'd notice that it would explode with a `SyntaxError`. You are better off learning the syntax of JavaScript before doing anything related to xhr. [jQuery Fundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/) is a good place to start with.

Comment: That's my requirement, I don't want to store the cookies which returns from ajax service call in some scenarios. The below post is working fine for me. Thank's Barmar

Comment: You're missing my point. StackOverflow is for helping people solve real problems and spread knowledge, not do the job for someone who's not willing to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: flag == 'Y'
}
```

However, if you really need to omit the option entirely when `flag` != 'Y', you can do:

```
xhrFieldsObj = {
   /* You can put all the static options in here */
};
if (flag == 'Y') {
    xhrFieldsObj.withCredentials = true;
};
...
   xhrFields: xhrFieldsObj
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var xhrFields = {};

if (flag == 'Y') {
    xhrFields.withCredentials = true;
}
```